# Read data from excel sheet as it is

Tags: excel, selenium, readfile

I need to read the data form the excel sheet.
In a cell, the data is 30.44% but when I read the data from the cell the output is 0.3044, and the output I need is 30.44% as it is from the excel

```
public String getDataFromExcelWithColNo(String sheetname, String colno, String rowno) {
        String data = null;
        try {
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(filepath);
            sheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetname);
             XSSFRow firstrow = sheet.getRow(Integer.parseInt(rowno));
            int col = Integer.parseInt(colno);
            try {
                int celltype = sheet.getRow((Integer.parseInt(rowno)) - 1).getCell(col - 1).getCellType();
                if (celltype == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                    data = sheet.getRow((Integer.parseInt(rowno)) - 1).getCell(col - 1).getStringCellValue().toString()
                            .trim();
                    System.out.println("Value: " + data);
                } else if (celltype == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                    data = Double.toString(
                            sheet.getRow((Integer.parseInt(rowno)) - 1).getCell(col - 1).getNumericCellValue());
                } else if (celltype == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN) {
                    data = String.valueOf(
                            sheet.getRow((Integer.parseInt(rowno)) - 1).getCell(col - 1).getBooleanCellValue());
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException ne) {
                System.out.println("Returning null value.");
                data = "";
            }
        } catch (IOException io) {

        }
        return data;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find if a cell is formatted as a percentage by testing the cell data format

```
else if (celltype == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                    if (cellstyle.getDataFormatString().contains("%")) {
                        data = Double.toString(sheet.getRow((Integer.parseInt(rowno)) - 1).getCell(col - 1).getNumericCellValue()*100);
                        System.out.println("Value: " + data + "%");
                    } else {
                        data = Double.toString(sheet.getRow((Integer.parseInt(rowno)) - 1).getCell(col - 1).getNumericCellValue());
                        System.out.println("Value: " + data);
                    }
```

**Complete Block :**

```
try {
                CellType celltype = sheet.getRow((Integer.parseInt(rowno)) - 1).getCell(col - 1).getCellType();
                CellStyle cellstyle = sheet.getRow((Integer.parseInt(rowno)) - 1).getCell(col - 1).getCellStyle();
                if (celltype == CellType.STRING) {
                    data = sheet.getRow((Integer.parseInt(rowno)) - 1).getCell(col - 1).getStringCellValue().toString()
                            .trim();
                    System.out.println("Value: " + data);
                } else if (celltype == CellType.NUMERIC) {
                    if (cellstyle.getDataFormatString().contains("%")) {
                        data = Double.toString(sheet.getRow((Integer.parseInt(rowno)) - 1).getCell(col - 1).getNumericCellValue()*100);
                        System.out.println("Value: " + data + "%");
                    } else {
                        data = Double.toString(sheet.getRow((Integer.parseInt(rowno)) - 1).getCell(col - 1).getNumericCellValue());
                        System.out.println("Value: " + data);
                    }
                } else if (celltype == CellType.BOOLEAN) {
                    data = String.valueOf(
                            sheet.getRow((Integer.parseInt(rowno)) - 1).getCell(col - 1).getBooleanCellValue());
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException ne) {
                System.out.println("Returning null value.");
                data = "";
            }
        }
```

[image]